# Name of socketed PCB jumpers

Tags: pcb, wire, jumper, socket

What is the correct name for those little jumper cables, with a small socket each end, designed to go between header pins on PCBs. A bit like these, but singles

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/5-Pcs-30cm-Length-3-Pins-PCB-Board-Jumper-Wire-Cable-Connecters-/121208591808?pt=UK_BOI_Electrical_Components_Supplies_ET&hash=item1c389855c0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly common to call them "dupont" cables regardless of how many conductors it contains.

Comment: Thanks - never heard the name even after decades in the business! Maybe it's mainly a US thing. Anyway, I found some (overpriced) on RS using combinations of words like "jumper" and "pcb" etc. However, entering you suggestion brought up a load of cheap stuff on eBay - ideal!

Comment: I don't think it actually ever had a specific name until someone got tired of it not having a name and pulled one out of thin air.

Comment: A vast amount on www.dx.com