# how do I connect the infrared distance sensor to the breadboard?

Tags: sensor, infrared, breadboard

Someone said I  was suppose connect the analog to digital converter and the infrared distance sensor to the breadboard by following this link:http://raspberry.io/projects/view/reading-from-a-mcp3002-analog-to-digital-converter/#step1 Through this link I have to substitute the potentiometer in the example for the Infrared Distance Sensor but the problem is I can't connect the Infrared Distance Sensor to the Breadboard because of the end the three cables wires

[image]

Comment: Peel off the wire jacket.

Answer (score 0):

Strip the wires. If they're stranded, might want to solder on a bit of solid core wire to the end to make them contact better.

Comment: How do I strip the wires can you please provide me specific details on how to strip the wires?

Comment: They make tools for it; google "wire strippers". Of course, you can also cut the insulation off using a knife, ordinary scissors, or if you're really desperate, your teeth.

Comment: After when I strip the wires how do I solder them to connect to the breadboard?

Comment: You _can_ just shove them into the breadboard, but if they're stranded wires it's likely you'll eventually have a few strands break off and get stuck in your breadboard, which is never fun. Get a small piece of solid-core wire (22 AWG works well for breadboards, I find) and solder it onto the end of the wire. If you're unfamiliar with soldering, there are plenty of tutorials on the internet. I recommend keeping some burn treatment nearby your first time!

Comment: I'm very Unfamiliar on how to solder the wires can you provide me some tutorial links on how to do it, and also can you provide me the link on where to buy the solid core wire

Comment: Just search youtube, really. I think Dave Jones (EEVBlog) has a few good ones.

Answer (score 0):

I crimp ["Dupont"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108476/name-of-socketed-pcb-jumpers/108477#108477) pins onto the end and put them into a Dupont header. That way I don't have to deal with either soldering or bent stranded wires. The flip side is that it takes a bit of experience to crimp them, especially if you don't actually have a proper tool for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best and easiest way is solder 3mm of stripped end to end of a 1/4 W resistor (steel is stronger than copper wire core) then cut off 3-5mm from solderpoint thus cutting off <1cm of resistor wire.

The cable strands work but more likely to interfere with bi-contacts.

- twist both sensor wires for improved distance from noise immunity. Decouple supply ripple well.

This just looks like a dual PD sensor with a central emitter however and if you don't know how to terminate wire, you likely have much much more to learn about emitter/detector designs for distance measurements , better than this one.

> But you have to know what you expect or want, with measurable spec's.